# Attach Files not shown in Create Case Form in Community

Tags: community, servicecloud, community-builder

I am working on the Create Case Form in a community in order to allow people to submit cases from the community.

In the community builder, when working on the Create Case Form, there is a checkbox named "Attach files". If I check this checkbox then a nice link shows up in the preview window allowing the user to attach a file. However, after publishing the community and looking at that page as a not-logged in user, that attach file link is not there. Everything else shows up fine in the form.

The guest profile has Read and Create rights to Case object and the form works properly, cases are created.

What am I missing? How do I make the attach files link appear in this form in the community?

Comment: Which template are you using?

Comment: I think the keyword on your question is "not-logged in user". Notes and Attachments are mainly used for salesforce users and not for external users.

Comment: We are using Koa Spring '16. @SeanSoriano you mean that it might not be possible at all for guest users to attach files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately "Guest users can’t attach files when creating a case" (from the "Set Up and Manage Salesforce Communities" guide.